# Sails query keep rendering undefined object

Tags: javascript, sql, sails.js

I am querying from my sails API in my postgres db :

```
Foot.query("SELECT id FROM foot WHERE foot.date <'"+nowMinus3d+"' AND date >'"+nowMinus4d+"'", function(err, results){
      _.each(results.rows, function(result, err){
        console.log(result["id"]);
        Player.query("SELECT player.user FROM player WHERE (player.statut = 2 OR player.statut = 3) AND player.foot ='"+results.rows["id"]+"'", function(err, players){

          console.log(players);
        })
      })
    })
  },
```

Everything works fine until I enter the second query : `Player.query`, here I keep getting undefined for `console.log(players)`. I tested the query in Pgadmin interface and I think i should be getting an object with [{user: 2}, {user: 1}] somewhere for `players`.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using results.rows["id"] in the second query. Which I guess will be null or underfined. 
BTW, you should test the "err" first. And you might want to use "in" instead of sending querys in a loop.

Comment: MYSQL IN: something like
SELECT player.user FROM player WHERE (player.statut = 2 OR player.statut = 3) AND player.foot in (x,y,z)